# Query listing customers who ordered between dates and not ordered between dates

Tags: postgresql, date, between

I have two tables `customers` which has many `orders`.

I would like to list customers who ordered between dates but not order (after) between later dates. I would like to figure out which customers didn't not return.

I can write write query where I can list customers which ordered between dates.

```
SELECT
    "customers".* 
FROM
    "customers"
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = customers.ID 
    AND orders.deleted_at IS NULL 
    AND ( orders.created_at BETWEEN '2020/06/05' AND '2020/06/13' ) 
WHERE
    ( orders.customer_id IS NOT NULL ) 
GROUP BY
    customers.ID
```

I can write also query which will give me a list who did not order between dates

```
SELECT
    "customers".* 
FROM
    "customers"
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = customers.ID 
    AND orders.deleted_at IS NULL 
    AND ( orders.created_at BETWEEN '2020/06/16' AND '2020/06/18' ) 
WHERE
    ( orders.customer_id IS NULL ) 
GROUP BY
    customers.ID
```

but cannot figure out how to have this list in one query.

My last query (which don't work)

```
SELECT  
"customers".*
FROM "customers" 

LEFT JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" AND "orders"."deleted_at" IS NULL 

WHERE 

-- LAST WEEK
AND (orders.created_at BETWEEN '2020/06/05' AND '2020/06/13' AND orders.customer_id IS NOT NULL) 
-- NOT ORDERED TODAY 
AND (orders.created_at BETWEEN '2020/06/16' AND '2020/06/18' AND orders.customer_id IS NULL)

GROUP BY customers.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of EXISTS and NOT EXISTS:

```
select cust.* 
  from "customers" cust
where
      exists 
           (select null 
              from orders ord1
             where ord1.customer_id = cust.id
               and ord1.created_at between date '2020-06-05' and date '2020-06-13'
           )              
  and not exists 
          ( select null 
              from orders ord2
             where ord2.customer_id = cust.id
               and ord2.created_at between date '2020-06-16' and date '2020-06-18'
          ) ;
```

This should perform quite well especially if you have an index orders(customer_id, created_at).

Comment: thanks, this one is shortest clear and working solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know in comments if it does not work for you or if you want an explanation for any part of it.

```
with params as (
  select '2020/06/05' as r1start, '2020/06/13' as r1end, 
         '2020/06/16' as r2start, '2020/06/18' as r2end
) ordersinfo as (
  SELECT customers.id,
         MAX(CASE 
               WHEN orders.created_at between p.r1start and p.r1end then 1
               ELSE 0
             END) as r1order,
         MAX(CASE 
               WHEN orders.created_at between p.r2start and p.r2end then 1
               ELSE 0
             END) as r2order
    FROM customers
    CROSS JOIN params p
    JOIN orders 
      ON orders.customer_id = customers.ID 
     AND orders.deleted_at IS NULL 
     AND ( orders.created_at BETWEEN p.r1start AND p.r2end ) 
  GROUP BY customers.ID
)
select c.*
  from ordersinfo o
  join customers c on c.id = o.id 
 where o.r1order = 1 and o.r2order = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL lets you [combine](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-union.html) query results - in this case you seem to be looking for `INTERSECT`. It gives you a set of records that match both of those queries. You can just take the first on and intersect its results with the other one, without rewriting anything:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM --here goes your first query
   (SELECT
        "customers".* 
    FROM
        "customers"
        LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = customers.ID 
        AND orders.deleted_at IS NULL 
        AND ( orders.created_at BETWEEN '2020/06/05' AND '2020/06/13' ) 
    WHERE
        ( orders.customer_id IS NOT NULL ) 
    GROUP BY
        customers.ID
    ) a
INTERSECT --here you put your other query
   (SELECT 
        "customers".* 
    FROM
        "customers"
        LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = customers.ID 
        AND orders.deleted_at IS NULL 
        AND ( orders.created_at BETWEEN '2020/06/16' AND '2020/06/18' ) 
    WHERE
        ( orders.customer_id IS NULL ) 
    GROUP BY
        customers.ID 
    );
```

If you want to keep duplicates, combine them with `INTERSECT ALL` instead.

There are multiple ways you could rewrite your query to get the results you're after in one go and without this mechanism, but combining results using `UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` is a very useful tool in situations like this, when you struggle to come up with a single query with a single set of conditions that would give you the results you want. It's worth noting that on a certain scale performance might become a bigger concern than the difficulty of your query optimisation.